# How do you get a triple perfect?

Tags: runner2

I can't seem to figure out how to get a "triple perfect" in Runner2. I know you get a first perfect for collecting all the gold and a second perfect for hitting the bullseye, but how do you get a triple perfect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little terminology :

A **Perfect** means *collecting all the gold in a level*.
*Hitting the bullseye on top of that* is not a "Double Perfect" but a **Perfect +** (for the + sign on the exclamation point on the map).
A **Triple Perfect**, then, is *getting a perfect on every difficulty level for a given level*.
And hitting the bullseye at the end for each would be a **Triple Perfect +**.